# graphics path and iCloud problem

Tags: includegraphics

My graphics folder is located to the desktop which is connected to a iCloud account. My problem occur when i tried to compile the preamble and in that second there was a power shutdown, since then it cannot compile the pictures and .pdf files.I always have an error "./thesi.tex:772: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'Ptyxioa.jpg'", I tried to set another image folder but still I have the same error. Shall I upload the folder to a Dropbox account? How can I find the path from the Dropbox ?
Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/home/Petros/auth/} }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=15cm]{Ptyxioa.jpg}
\centering \selectlanguage{greek}
\hyperlink{Ptyxioa.pdf}{Πιστοποιητικά $6.2$}
\hypertarget{Ptyxioa.pdf}{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `Ptyxioa.jpg` actually there? And if it is on the desktop how is that related to your choice of `\graphicspath`. Thirdly your cited error is clearly not related to the given MWE as it does not have 772 lines.

Comment: it was clearly an example it is quite large file, more than 772 lines. Ptyxioa is included in the folder auth..

Comment: Then please provide the log from a compilation of his mwe